# How do I get this collapsible DIV to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I seen another member post this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q4PUw/2/
But I can't get it to work.

He used someone else's example with the `<div class="sitesection">` so I'm not sure how that works. All I want is a link that says "Expand" and it the text will scroll out after the link is clicked.

What is the javascript part supposed to look like? 
This: ?

```
<script language="javascript">
$('.expand-one').click(function(){
    $('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
```

I believe I messed the DIV up, as I don't know where to use it. But when I click the link in the example, it just brings up www.mysite.com/page.html#
As the ahref is #.

Comment: can you post YOUR fiddle so we can see what you did wrong?

Comment: If you click on the jsfiddle, does it work as you expect? It sounds like you are trying to copy this but missed some part of it but we can't see what your problem is. Why not post your code on jsfiddle (just click fork on the example, make your changes, save it and link it here).

Comment: do you have jquery included in your javascript

Comment: What's the !DOCTYPE in use for declaring scripting language ? "<script language="javascript">" ??

Comment: Thankyou for the quick replies. I've never even seen fiddle before until now. The one I linked does work for me. I honestly don't have a clue what I'm doing. I'm just plugging away and trying trial and error. All I did was put in the above script code, {<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>}  and copied the html exactly as it's shown. In the jsfiddle linked above, I'm not 100% sure what I do with the javascript code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if you click an anchor, the native browser behaviour will be follow the href url, so you have to prevent the Default behaviour of a anchor tag.

try with this:

```
<script language="javascript">
 $('.expand-one').click(function(event){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
```

Comment: "the native browser behaviour will be to follow the href url"

Comment: Yes and Milche said, it's doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/yJ8gH/) again :)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="expand" data-class="one">Click Here To Display The Content</a>

<p class="content one">
  This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"
</p>

<a href="#" class="expand" data-class="two">Click Here To Display The Content</a>

<p class="content two">
  This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"
</p>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.expand').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var dataClass = $(this).attr('data-class');    

  $('.content.'+dataClass).fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
  display: none;
}
.expand {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;

  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;

  transition: color 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
}
.expand:hover {
  color: #47b7ef;
}
```

*Note: Put the script just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: I don't know, I'm doing something wrong. I'm making a noob mistake, I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing. I'm sure it has to do with the javascript. Is this incorrect?
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.expand-one').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content-one').fadeToggle('slow');
});
</script>

Comment: Go to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) site and download the compressed, production jQuery 1.10.2 than put it in your root folder and everything it's gonna work ;) Of course call it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` or if you're using HTML5 than `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: *** Okay, I got it. It wasn't working when I put it in head section, but worked just before body. Is that normal? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Always put scripts just before `</body>` , you can put libraries in the `<head></head>` section, but scripts always just before `</body>`.

Comment: uh oh, have another issue. I want to do about 10 different ones on one page, how do I do that? When I do it now it expands all of them. Is it hard to do?

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much. It works, but it defaults to showing the text. When I click it, it goes away, but I'd prefer it hidden in the beginning. Also, I'm going to be doing about 12 items. Could you please show me how to make the CSS for it as clean as possible? Thanks again for your time, appreciate it so much.

Comment: Please look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/yJ8gH/) and about CSS set content to display none like in example above `content { display: none; }`

Comment: One little thing, and I should know this, but the a link styling in the CSS is messing up my page layout with my other alinks in the page. How can I change it so it only affects the links for this?

Comment: You're welcome, look at the new Fiddle, I've update it again ;)